# $_POST large string stucks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I send a base64 encoded string using `$.post`. Its length is `1000000+` (less than 2M)

When I grab it with PHP $_POST it crashes (504 or 424 error returns).
Each returns after a big timeout.

Its ok for lower string length `< 900000`. But for length `900000` the response timeout is 15-30 seconds!!!

To check it I used this code:

javascript:

```
var string = '...';
console.log(string.lenght); 

$.post("save.php", {
    data: string
}, function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

save.php:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo strlen($data);
```

On my local machine everything is ok. Can anyone explain whats happening?
Why it takes so long? Why can't I normally send data over `900000` chars?

I also checked server properties:

```
memory_limit 128M
post_max_size 100M
max_input_vars 10000
upload_max_filesize 100M
```

Comment: try to set `set_time_limit(0);` in php.

Comment: You said everything is ok on your local machine, then in what server environment are you getting this problem? And BTW, why would you use base64 when doing post, which will largely increase the data size? Base64 are only helpful when you really need to express binary data in readable characters.

Comment: My guess is that your production environment has a firewall, and treats posts which are not multipart file upload and larger than 900000, as attacks and refuses to serve this request.

Comment: Yes, you are right! the server has a firewall. So I just contacted them.

Comment: About base64: I grab a png data from canvas and its already encoded. Should I decode it first and then transfer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TwilightSun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642457/post-large-string-stucks/28651410#comment45584088_28642457) answered the question. The server has a firewall.